# Selected Row+1 in Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, row, selected

Is there any way to select the next row to the selected row in c# (gridview)?

For example if i choose the second row it will select the third row

```
protected void ProjectsTBL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = ProjectsTBL.SelectedRow;
    Session["selectedrow"] = row;
    Response.Redirect("ProjectDetails.aspx");
}
```

In Asp.net

Answer (score 1):

Try this sample code:

```
protected void ProjectsTBL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get index of the currently selected row:
    int rowIndex = ProjectsTBL.SelectedIndex;

    // Verify the row exists and it's not the last row:
    if (rowIndex < 0 || rowIndex >= ProjectsTBL.Rows.Count - 1)
        return;

    // Get the next row:
    Session["selectedrow"] = ProjectsTBL.Rows[rowIndex + 1];
    Response.Redirect("ProjectDetails.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void ProjectsTBL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = ProjectsTBL.SelectedRow;
    if (row.RowIndex >= ProjectsTBL.Rows.Count - 1) { return; }

    GridViewRow selectedRow = ProjectsTBL.Rows[row.RowIndex + 1];

    row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Normal;
    selectedRow.RowState = DataControlRowState.Selected;

    Session["selectedrow"] = selectedRow;
    Response.Redirect("ProjectDetails.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
          int selIndex = e.RowIndex;
          int newSelIndex = selIndex + 1;
          DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows[newSelIndex].Cells[0];
    }
}
```

Try This I hope This Help

Comment: DataGridView is Name of Ur DataGridView click on Grid and see in the properties for Its Name
Yup for Winform

Comment: This is not the control the OP is asking about.  He is asking about an ASP.Net `GridView`...